# Why don't HTML ids work like namespaces?

Tags: html

It would seem natural to me that HTML would support this:

```
<div id="comment1">
    <div id="helpText">...</div>
</div>

<div id="comment2">
    <div id="helpText">...</div>
</div>

<div id="comment3">
    <div id="helpText">...</div>
</div>

#comment1#helpText
#comment2#helpText
#comment3#helpText
```

But since HTML ids must be unique, I need to do this:

```
<div id="comment1">
    <div id="helpText1">...</div>
</div>

<div id="comment2">
    <div id="helpText2">...</div>
</div>

<div id="comment3">
    <div id="helpText3">...</div>
</div>

#comment1#helpText1
#comment2#helpText2
#comment3#helpText3
```

This seems to be unnecessarily redundant, especially when I have multiple nested DIVs:

```
<div id="comment1">
    <div id="header1">...</div>
    <div id="introduction1">...</div>
    <div id="helpText1">...</div>
    <div id="footer1">...</div>
</div>

<div id="comment2">
    <div id="header2">...</div>
    <div id="introduction2">...</div>
    <div id="helpText2">...</div>
    <div id="footer2">...</div>
</div>

<div id="comment3">
    <div id="header3">...</div>
    <div id="introduction3">...</div>
    <div id="helpText3">...</div>
    <div id="footer3">...</div>
</div>
```

Can anyone give me some background as to why this is the case and perhaps some workarounds for getting HTML ids to work more along the lines of a namespace metaphor?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `class`.

An `id` identifies that element and that element alone.  It's like a pointer to an object in C++.  Elements without an `id` are like objects without named (?) pointers to them.

`Class`es are like attributes.  Elements may have zero or more of any combination of `class`es.  They give you what you want.

```
/* CSS */
#comment1 .header
#comment3 .helpText

<!-- (X)HTML -->
<div id="comment1">
    <div class="header">...</div>
    <div class="introduction">...</div>
    <div class="helpText">...</div>
    <div class="footer">...</div>
</div>
```

DOM by itself does not have nice selectors for Javascript (and other scripting languages), but toolkits like JQuery allow you to select elements by class name nicely.

Comment: Firefox supports getElementsByClassName (since version 3 I think) Let's hope that other browsers will support it too soon :)

Answer (score 3):

In the first example you can use this:

```
#comment1 .helpText
#comment2 .helpText
#comment3 .helpText
```

You don't have to define an id for the helpText elements, but a class with `class="helpText"`.

You can also manipulate all children divs by using the following rules:

```
#comment1 div
#comment2 div
#comment3 div
```

If you want to manipulate all children of a "comment" node you cnn add `class="comment"` to these comment divs and access them with

```
div.comment
```

Answer (score 3):

You might actually want to ask the question, "why do we need IDs in CSS at all?" -- if a class can be either unique or non-unique, why do we need another kind of identifier with the necessity to be unique?

My answer would be that we don't actually need them in CSS, but they're needed for other purposes in the DOM. For instance the `<label>` element can identify which other element it's labelling, using that element's unique ID.

And if they're going to be there in the DOM, we need access to them in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Use classes.

Comment: Beat me by 42 seconds (no joke).  But my answer is more explanatory (I would say) on why it can be used.

Comment: It's not unfair, in my view.  It's not an answer, just a comment.  If the questioner knew how to use classes in this manner, then they wouldn't have asked the question.  Answers, in my view need to explain _why_ and _how_ one should use an approach.  'Use classes' doesn't tell the questioner anything useful.

Comment: @nicodemus13: It's a complete answer for a programmer. We are not here to hold your hand. HTML and CSS have very good documentation. Sometimes all it needs is a keyword to take a shortcut.

Comment: @stesch: Not, it isn't.  It's a complete answer for someone who already knows the answer.  This site is is useful to help and teach people.  Your approach would reduce the entire site to 'RTFM', 'Bug', 'Behaviour as designed'.  Not to mention CSS is a obsure approach in itself.  There seems to be quite a bit of crypto-aggressiveness on some of these sites.

Answer (score 1):

What stesch said. Like this:

```
 <div id="comment1">
    <div class="helpText">...</div>
</div>

<div id="comment2">
    <div class="helpText">...</div>
</div>

<div id="comment3">
    <div class="helpText">...</div>
</div>
```

and then:

```
#comment1.helpText
#comment2.helpText
#comment3.helpText
```

Comment: Your selectors refer to an element like `<div id="comment1" class="helpText">` etc.

Answer (score 0):

as strager writes: use class.

And remember, an element can belong to several classes at once:

```
<div id="comment1">
    <div class="header introduction">...</div>
    <div class="introduction">...</div>
    <div class="footer introduction somethingelse">...</div>
</div>
```